# I set double YAxis but it doesn't follow the directions(left,right) and datasets

Tags: vue.js, charts, chart.js, vuejs3, axis

I wanna set double yAxis, so I wrote down the code like below

```js
const data = {
        labels: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
        datasets: [
          {
            type: 'bar',
            label: this.$t('numberOfBuilding'),
            data: [100, 20, 30, 5, 5],
            backgroundColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: ['rgb(255, 99, 132)', 'rgb(255, 159, 64)', 'rgb(255, 205, 86)', 'rgb(75, 192, 192)', 'rgb(54, 162, 235)'],
            borderWidth: 1,
            yAxisId: 'y'
          },
          // {
          //   type: 'line',
          //   fill: true,
          //   label: this.$t('output') + '(' + this.$t('criteriaMonth') + ')',
          //   data: [200, 500, 600, 800, 1000],
          //   borderColor: 'rgba(255, 201, 14, 1)',
          //   backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 201, 14, 0.5)',
          //   lineTension: 0.2,
          //   yAxisId: 'y1'
          // },
          {
            type: 'line',
            fill: true,
            label: this.$t('output') + '(' + this.$t('sum') + ')', 
            data: [300, 100, 700, 249, 588],
            borderColor: 'rgba(55, 201, 14, 1)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(55, 201, 14, 0.5)',
            lineTension: 0.2,
            yAxisId: 'y1'
          }
        ]
      }
```

```
const config = {
        type: 'scatter',
        data: data,
        options: {
          scales: {
            y: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              position: 'left'
            },
            y1: {
              position: 'right',
              grid: {
                drawOnChartArea: false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

but it doesn't work properly
yAxis which id is 'y1' is at left and datasets[0] which has 'y' as yAxisId presents with 'y1' axis
it seems like yAxisId doesn't connect well with their own datasets
See the below pictures
[result of above code]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0moGR.png)

but my another code is work well I don't know what different it is
here's my another code which works well

```
const data = {
        labels: [
          1 + this.$t('month'),
          2 + this.$t('month'),
          3 + this.$t('month'),
          4 + this.$t('month'),
          5 + this.$t('month'),
          6 + this.$t('month'),
          7 + this.$t('month'),
          8 + this.$t('month'),
          9 + this.$t('month'),
          10 + this.$t('month'),
          11 + this.$t('month'),
          12 + this.$t('month')
        ],
        datasets: [
          {
            type: 'bar',
            label: this.$t('totalConsumption') + '(' + this.unit + ')',
            data: this.consumptionData,
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            yAxisID: 'y'
          },
          {
            type: 'line',
            label: this.$t('temperatureAVG') + '(℃)',
            data: this.temperatureData,
            fill: false,
            borderColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
            yAxisID: 'y1'
          }
        ]
      }
```

```
const config = {
        type: 'scatter',
        data: data,
        options: {
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          scales: {
            y: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              position: 'left'
            },
            y1: {
              position: 'right',
              grid: {
                drawOnChartArea: false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first code, the option name is wrong. You are using `yAxisId` but the correct one is `yAxisID` (as in the second sample), id must be uppercase